# Why google font oswald is not displayed in firefox and chrome but is in other web browser?

Tags: css, browser, fonts, google-api

I have a problem with the oswald font that is not showing up in chrome or firefox (but does in other browsers).

The "Oswald" font is included in the head of my page through the google api. Everything was working well since the project I work on was launched. But for a few days now, the oswald font do not display anymore in firefox and chrome on my website.

As I did not change anything, I went to the [oswald font google page](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Oswald) and... after the page loaded (about 0,5 seconds), the charcaters disappeared and finally, almost no characters left on the page :

[image: oswald page empty]

During the page load, all the characters were shown but just after the load, most of the characters had disappeared.

I have this problem with Chromium (73.0.3683.75) and with Firefox Developer Edition (68.0b6).

Firefox quantum 60.7.0esr works fine. 
The default web browser of debian "Web for gnome" also shows the characters.

Disabling extensions in FFDE or Chromium does not change anything. 
Emptying the cache or navigating in a private tab does not solve the problem neither...

After reading an another post that it could be the problem, I set up ssl on my local environment, thinking that it may solve the problem as I was working on a non ssl environment before but it had no effect.

And also, the oswald font is not installed on my system (I read that sometimes a web font could conflicts with an installed font)

I'm running debian 9 and everything is up to date.

The font is included in the head of my page like this :

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
```

But again, it was working well before, I did not change anything on my website and also, I think it's more a browser related issue as the google font page stays empty...

Do you have any suggestion that could help ?

Thanks!

**Edit :** in fact, there are differences between the requests which are made in Firefox 60 ESR and Firefox 67.
I have ~ 60 requests on Firfox 60 (which is the one working fine) but ~ 200 requets on Firefox 67 : there is a lot of "CSP" request that are calling `https://fonts.google.com/cspreport`. Params of the requests looks like :

```
{"csp-report":{"blocked-uri":"eval","column-number":431,"document-uri":"https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Oswald","line-number":255,"original-policy":"script-src 'nonce-2z773xrHIL8xPC8zrWt9rg' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'none'; base-uri 'self'; worker-src 'self'; report-uri https://fonts.google.com/cspreport","referrer":"","source-file":"https://www.gstatic.com/_/fonts/_/js/k=fonts.app.en_US.1FRZ-Rc5dfA.O/d=1/rs=AE60u5dKHjXqj5PvI9I4JceHuPgo4zd3lw/m=core%20line%2038%20%3E%20eval","violated-directive":"script-src"}}
```

Edit 2 : For information, here is the link to the bug somebody opened in debian bugtracker : https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=929982

Comment: Works as expected for me in Chrome and FrieFox

Comment: Thanks. I also checked on my mobile and it works fine... If you have any suggestion I would be glad to try it

Comment: You can try looking for adblockers/any other extensions which could be causing this issue. Also, check the console for errors; see the network tab to check if the font actually loaded (right click -> inspect) EDIT: you can try incognito window/private browsing to check if it's an extension that's causing this issue.

Comment: Thanks @Palash Karia I already tried the private browsing and it does not works. Also, as mentioned before, I tried to reload the page with my few extensions disabled without any success. I do not have any errors in the console (I forgot to mention it before) and the foots looks well loaded (200 code for the first load withotu any cache, 304 code then because it's in cache)

Comment: Chances are you installed a modified (broken) version of the font on your OS and it's used instead of the webfont. While clearly not recommended, you can disable this behavior by hosting the webfont on your own website under a different font family name. Another, proper solution would be to uninstall the font from your system. I'd be curious to know if the installed font works with other applications.

Comment: Hello @AndreiGheorghiu I already looked for the font on my system and I can't find it, neither in the files nor in the installed fonts. Moreover, as said previously, it works fine in firefox but does not in firefox developer edition orin chromium

Comment: In that case my assumption was wrong. Is there any difference between the request headers of the two different browser versions? You could also scan the changelist for fonts rendering mods.

Comment: Nice one @AndreiGheorghiu, I checked and dedited my answer with some more information about the requests made when loading the fonts. There is a lot more requests on the firefox version which is not displaying the font. You can check my edited answer for more information!

Comment: FYI. Work fine on Chromium 74.0.3729.169 & FFDE 68.0b7 under Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I asked a friend of mine to try (he's on chrome) to try and it does not works neither on his computer (also debian).. Maybe it is something debian related... I'll update if I find out what is the problem.

Comment: I add myself to the list, it's a problem with Debian

Answer (score 2):

Same problem for me since few days.... Oswald font not displaying on firefox nor chrome (on linux)...

I have found a "workaround" but it is not very pretty :/

font-family: "Oswald"  => not working

font-family: "Oswald " => works

I just added a blank space after the name of the font and it works ?!?!?

But I can't explain why... it was working well since the website is online (2013)... I didn't update anything on my computer....

Comment: Hello @souvrard ! I don't know why but your workaround seems to work. It seems like a bug on the most recent versions of the browsers. Or maybe something changed on google side lastly.As a workaround, if it can help you,I use Firefox ESR which is the version included in lunix distros and which is not really up to date with the latest updates (only securities update are made).FF ESR is at version ~60 while FF standard is at version 67.Not satisfying as we could be many to go through this bug. Anyway, thanks for your update, I don't feel alone anymore now :) I'll let you know if I find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your feedback.

I didn't mention it but I have the "bug" on Firefox 67.0.1 and Chromium 73.0.3683.75 builds on Debian 9.8 (64 bits)...

Comment: I also have this issue in Firefox Developer 68.0b4 (64-bit). But it is fine in Firefox Quantum 60.7.0esr (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

The problem seen here was introduced with [[truetype] Another GX sanity test.](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/freetype/freetype2.git/commit/?id=052f6c5649f7a46e599742eb6f47fa91d090f77e) in FreeType VER-2-6-2 and fixed with [[truetype] More fixes for handling of GX deltas.](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/freetype/freetype2.git/commit/?id=4e659d7eadb2cb17c28f1c23ac77cebd7b7e3e33) in FreeType VER-2-7. This will affect Chromium and Firefox as they are using the [system FreeType which on debian 9 appears to be based on 2.6.3](https://packages.debian.org/source/stretch/freetype). This should not affect Google Chrome since it ships its own version of FreeType.

You may wish to ask the debian maintainer to apply [[truetype] More fixes for handling of GX deltas.](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/freetype/freetype2.git/commit/?id=4e659d7eadb2cb17c28f1c23ac77cebd7b7e3e33)
 to FreeType from 2.6.2 to 2.6.5 which are all affected by this issue. This appears to cherry-pick cleanly onto VER-2-6-3, and I've verified that doing so fixes this issue.

Note that this is a different issue from the [incorrect advances for variable fonts in FreeType](https://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/index.php?56601). That issue was introduced in VER-2-9 and fixed post VER-2-10-1.